# Assert one value in an array of similar fields with JSONPath validation in Soap UI

Tags: arrays, json, soapui

I have the following type of JSON Response after I execute a Rest reqeust:

```
"returned tag[1]":"value"
"returned tag[2]":"value"
"returned tag[3]":"value"
"returned tag[4]":"value"
"returned tag[5]":"value"
```

Based on specific tests I can have certain value returned in one of the multiple fields that are generated. I want to make a Soap UI assertion of JSONPath Match type that will validate if this value is present in one of the fields, doesn't matter in which one. Currently I am trying like this:

```
JSONPath Expression:
$.data.['(returned tag[*])']

Expected Result:
A1
```

And I expect to validate if value A1 is present in one of the tags, which it is, but it is not working. If I specify a specific segment of the array in the Expression I am getting it right.

Please, can someone help me with that? :)

Comment: can you show a valid json example, please  ? thanks

Comment: `"Reason Code[1]": "R1",
      "Reason Code[2]": "P5",
      "Reason Code[3]": "P2",
      "Reason Code[4]": null,
      "Reason Code[5]": null,`

I want to assert via JSONPath assertion that R1 is contained in one of the 5 Reason Code fields. Based on the test it can be in any of the 5 ... I just need an assertion that checks in all of the array.

Comment: when you recover your json data in a variable, which is its type ? ie. response = myRequestJson, print the value of response.getClass(). thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am using the SoapUI pre-made assertions i.e. clicking the Add assertion in the response window and adding the mentioned type of assertion. I basically have the response window and match it with the Jason Path Match assertion where in the upper part I have to describe the regular expression and on the bottom the expected value. I am not using any code to receive teh response here.